# How to search both children and parent fields in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index type "gifs", as well as a type "comments". Comments are a child of gifs. They both have fields for "tags".

I figured out how to find children with a specific tag value, but not how to find children and parents where the tag value could be in either the parent or the child.

```
{
    "index": "gifs",
    "size": 25,
    "from": 0,
    "type": "gifs",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "comments",
                        "query": {
                            "term": {
                                "tags": "cat"
                            }
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {
                            "name": "comments"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After several hours of googling and trying out different combinations in the bool, I'm ready to give up and write two separate queries.